ASP.NET Core : publishing to .NET 8.0 directory
We have a simple ASP.NET Core Web API and we are having an odd issue with publishing. It is publishing the web.config file to the publish dir, but all other files to the parent dir of the publish directory - why?
We tried the CLI and are getting the same result. I'm certain this was working earlier... I have deleted/re-added publishing profiles, but no glory ...
Thanks in advance

Check the project structure, web.config should be in project directory, miss placing can also cause this issue or any project file configuration of file contents.
